# Does Perl's IO::Select in Windows work with filehandles?

Tags: perl

Does [IO::Select](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IO::Select) in Windows work with filehandles?

```
$pid = open $handle, "-|", "$_command" || die "Cannot run $_command";
my $s = IO::Select->new();
$s->add($handle);
$s->add(\*STDIN);
while (1) {
    @ready = $s->can_read(30);
    if (scalar(@ready) > 0) {
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

My script continuously prints something to the screen, with open, the command gets started in the background but `can_read` always fails on Windows. Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See this [PerlMonks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=651768):

> `select` (the underlying system call used by `IO::Select`) only works for sockets in Windows.

[MSDN docs for select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141%28VS.85%29.aspx) confirm this:

> The `select` function determines the status of one or more sockets, waiting if necessary, to perform synchronous I/O.