# Perl - Calling other script and showing output as it runs

Tags: perl

I am writing a Perl script that asks for some inputs and then eventually runs another script passing those inputs as arguments. That script I'm calling has `print` outputs that specify the % of how much processing is done as it goes through a `foreach` loop.

Currently I'm calling the other Perl script like this:

```
   print `perl /path/to/script.pl -x 0990;`
```

This works fine, but only prints any output when that called script finishes... so for example, when that script finishes, the output I get is:

```
   Status: 100% Completed
   Done!
```

When I want to be getting the output of every % number.

Any possible solutions for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this works for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";
use IPC::Open3;
use IO::Select;

# forces a flush to stdout
$| = 1;

# open a process for writing, reading, and error
my $pid = open3(0,\*READ,0,"perl /path/to/script.pl -x 0990");

# reading process output in non-blocking mode
my $sel = new IO::Select();
$sel->add(\*READ);

# read process output until process returns
do {
 foreach my $h ($sel->can_read)
 {
  my $buf = '';
  sysread(READ,$buf,4096);
  if($buf){print "response->$buf"}
 }
 $kid = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG);
} while $kid > -1;
```

**EDITED:**

*This script is not working on Windows platform*

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  I was working on a solution, but you posted yours first (and mine wasn't working!), so I tried yours.  The DO loop runs for the exact length of time the child script run, but the FOREACH loop never gets entered.

Comment: @jimtut Work's here. it might be because your process doesn't have any output so `$sel->can_read` block never executed.

Comment: Works on my end. However it does ONLY the print outputs INSIDE the foreach loop in the script that gets called. There are a couple print outputs in that script that did NOT get shown during the process... any idea why that would behave like that? Is that snippet just looking for outputs inside a foreach?

Comment: Does your process prints to `stderr`?

Comment: Nvm - I added the `$| = 1` line and that seemed to include EVERYTHING that has a print output. Seems good to go now! Would love to know how you came to this solution...

Comment: I have the code copied exactly as above, and it doesn't work for me, even if I put the `$|=1` in the child script.   But, with `$|=1`in the child script, you can do this even more simply with just `system("perl /path/to/script.pl -x 0990")`, at least on Windows with ActivePerl.  I've read somewhere that system() on Windows might work differently than on *nix, but this does work on Windows (no need to print the system() call, the output just echoes to STDOUT).

Comment: @jimtut Well this script is not working on Windows platform, since `IO::Socket` on Windows works just for sockets see [Does Perl's IO::Select in Windows work with filehandles?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1701458/2096990)